# BesselJ in .net accord can't accept complex number

Tags: c#, math, calculator, complextype, bessel-functions

I want to pass complex number to bassel function in .net as you can see :

```
 Complex[,] F_k = new Complex[M, N];
 F_k[m,n] = ((2 * Bessel.J(1, new Complex(1, -1) * (2 * 0.0110/ 122))));
```

but I get this error :

Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Numerics.Complex' to 'double'

Is any Bessel function in .NET which can accept complex types?

Comment: Interesting question, maybe you can find an identity which relates Bessel J with a complex argument to other functions with real arguments. I haven't tried it, but it's something to look for. You might look at packages which implement Bessel functions for complex arguments and see how they do it -- whether they're applying identities, and, if so, which ones, or whether they are doing the whole computation over again. E.g. Sympy, Maxima, that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Matlab, here is a way.

The Bessel J function can be expressed in terms of the `0F1` generalized hypergeometric function:

[image]

Here is a demonstration with R:

```r
library(Bessel)
library(hypergeo)

z <- 1 + 1i
alpha <- 2

BesselJ(z, nu = alpha)
# 0.0415799+0.2473976i
(z/2)^alpha / gamma(alpha+1) * genhypergeo(NULL, alpha + 1, -z^2/4)
# 0.0415799+0.2473976i
```

The generalized hypergeometric functions are [available for Matlab](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/hypergeom.html).

I don't speak Matlab, but I think `0F1(beta, y)` should be `hypergeom([], beta, y)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .I had a mistake in my question ,I asked there is any function in matlab , but actually I am looking for a function in .net